# Properties of convex sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $C$ be a convex set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $x\in C$. Let $C_x=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^2:x+ty\in C\,\,\forall t\ge0\}$. Then, can we say for any two points $x,x'\in C$, $C_x=C_{x'}$?

I think yes. Specifically, since convex sets are closed with respect to $tx+(1-t)y$, therefore, I think both $C_x$ and $C_{x'}$ are convex sets with the same parameter $t$. However, the problem lies with the fact that $y\notin C$ in general in this case. Any ideas. Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true when $C$ is not closed.

Let $C=(0,\infty]\times\mathbb R \cup \{(0,0)\}$.

For $(x,y)\in C\setminus \{(0,0)\} $, $C_{(x,y)}=[0,\infty]\times\mathbb R$ while $C_{(0,0)}=C$.

---

Assume $C$ is closed. Let $x\neq x' \in C$. Let us prove that $C_x \subset C_{x'}$. Let $v\in C_x$ and $a\geq 0$. Note that
$$ x' + av = \lim_n \left( \underbrace{\left( 1-\frac 1n\right)x' + \frac{1}{n}(\underbrace{x+nav}_{\in C})}_{\in C}\right) $$
Since $C$ is closed, $x' + av \in C$ thus $x'\in C_x$ hence $C_x \subset C_{x'}$.

By symmetry, $C_{x'} \subset C_{x}$

Answer (score 1):

**$C_x$ is convex**

Suppose that $x \in C$ and take $y_0, y_1 \in C_{x}$ and $t \in [0, 1]$.

By definition of $C_x$, for any $s > 0$ we then have $x + s y_0 \in C$ and $x + s y_1 \in C$. Since $C$ is convex this implies that $C \ni (1-t)(x + s y_0) + t(x + s y_1) = x + s((1-t) y_0 + t y_1)$, so $(1-t) y_0 + t y_1 \in C_x$.

Comment: $C_x$ is more than just convex, it's actually a convex cone.

Comment: It's a cone by definition, convex by proof. Thus it's a convex cone. :-)